# Convert Fetchxml to Entitycollection for dynamic output column

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

i want to create a function that receive a string parameter, ( the fetch Xml)and  also a collection of strings ( Parameters )  , these parameters will have a key and a value ,  thes parameters will replace parameter in the FetchXML string  and return a EntiyCollection, 
this is my function :

```
public EntityCollection ConvertFtechXML(string fetchxml, List<myClass> parameters)
            {
                parameters = new List<myClass>
                {
                    new myClass { key = "", value = "" },          
                };
//example of fetchxml query: 
   fetchxml = @"<fetch mapping='logical'>
   <entity name='account'> <attribute name='accountid'/>
      <attribute name='name'/>
      <link-entity name='systemuser' to='owninguser'>
         <filter type='and'>
            <condition attribute='lastname' operator='ne' value='@Value' />
          </filter>
      </link-entity>
   </entity>
</fetch> ";
                EntityCollection result = organisationService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchxml));
                return result;
            }
```

My problem is how to call this function to create dynamic output column from xml like this link in msdn to create an output from dataTable; in my case i want to create an output form fetchxml 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136088.aspx

Comment: Are you just asking how to make the attributes returned by the Fetch Xml dynamic?

Comment: Yes I want to convert the fetchxml to dynamic output